# Is it true that $S(n)\otimes_S S(m)\cong S(n+m)$?

Tags: tensor-products, graded-rings

Convention: rings are unital and commutative.

Let $S=\bigoplus_{d\geq 0}S_d$ be a graded ring. For $n\in\mathbb Z$ let $S(n)$ be the graded $S$-module defined by $S(n)_d=S_{n+d}$. It is claimed in [Stacks Project (2.27.2)](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01MM) that the canonical map
$$ 
\phi:S(n)\otimes_S S(m)\to S(n+m),x\otimes y\mapsto xy
$$
is an isomorphism. Surjectivity for me is clear(*). Injectivity not. Since the tensor product commutes with direct sums, we have
$$ 
S(n)\otimes_S S(m)=\bigoplus_{i,j}S_{n+i}\otimes_S S_{m+j} 
$$
while
$$ 
S(n+m)=\bigoplus_d S_{n+m+d}. 
$$
Let's assume $n=m$. If we take $i\neq j$, then we have the direct summand
$$ 
(S_{n+i}\otimes S_{n+j})\oplus (S_{n+j}\otimes S_{n+i})\subset S(n)\otimes_S S(m). 
$$
Clearly then $(x\otimes y)\oplus (-y\otimes x)$ is mapped to zero. Where am I making a mistake? (assuming the claim that we have an isomorphism is correct)

(*) Thanks to thomasz pointing out that surjectivity isn't clear at all, here is a counter(**) example:

Take $S=k[x,y,z]$ with $\deg k=0,\deg x=1,\deg y=2,\deg z=3$. Then $S(1)\otimes_S S(2)\to S(3)$ doesn't reach $z\in S(3)$.

(**) This example doesn't work, as pointed out in the comments. I assumed we have an $\mathbb N$-grading, but in [Stacks Project (1.10.56)](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00JL) we have the following convention: graded rings have an $\mathbb N$-grading, while graded modules have a $\mathbb Z$-grading. The twist operation is defined for graded modules and yields a graded module. Thus $S(n)$ is $\mathbb Z$-graded (meaning that also for $d<0$ we have $S(n)_d=S_{n+d} $). With this in mind, surjectivity is clear; we can reach $x\in S(n+m)_d$ by $x\otimes 1\in S(n)_{m+d}\otimes S(m)_{-m}$).

Comment: Is surjectivity clear? If multiplication in $S$ is trivial, then I think it pretty obviously isn't surjective, unless $S(n+m)$ is zero. You need some hypotheses about $S$ at least.

Comment: @tomasz Let $x\in S_{n+m+d}$, then $x\otimes 1$ is mapped to $x$.

Comment: Even if your rings are unital, $1$ is $0$-graded, so it doesn't work unless $n=0$ or $m=0$.

Comment: @tomasz Sorry, you're right.

Comment: The same argument shows that it doesn't have to be injective, e.g. if $S(1)\cdot S(1)=0$ but $S(1)\neq 0$.

Comment: Perhaps they had $S=A[X_0,\dots,X_n]$ in mind. I'll leave a comment on StacksProject and await their reply.

Comment: I think the natural grading on $S(n)\otimes_S S(m)$ is given by $\bigoplus_{d\in\mathbf Z}\bigoplus_{i+j=d}S_{n+i}\otimes_{S_0} S_{m+j}$. Then the problem reduces to showing $\bigoplus_{i+j=d}S_{n+i}\otimes_{S_0} S_{m+j}$ is isomorphic to $S_{m+n+d}$, which seems reasonable. In your particular example, $z\otimes 1\in S_{1+\mathbf{2}}\otimes S_{2\mathbf{-2}}$ gets mapped to $z\in S(3)_0$.

Comment: @cqfd Ah, I assumed we had an $\mathbb N$-grading on $S(n)$, but I see confirmed on Stacks Project (1.10.56) that the twist is $\mathbb Z$-graded - and then you're right about my example. I do think my original argument that we don't necessarily have injectivity still holds, even with the grading of the tensor product in mind.

Comment: @tomasz I know you had the $\mathbb N$-grading in mind, but just to avoid future confusion: with the $\mathbb Z$-grading in mind, we have $1\in S(1)\cdot S(1)$ (even though this product notation isn't kosher, since we want to think of $S(1)$ as a module, and not as a ring), so if $S(1)\cdot S(1)=0$, then $S=S(2)=0$ (as abelian groups), so the isomorphism still holds.

Comment: The direct sum decomposition is invalid, the graded $S$-module $S$ is not the direct sum of homogeneous components (this does not even make sense: homogeneous components do not form a sub-$S$-module).

Comment: @Yai0Phah Yes, you are right, I addressed that in my answer. I didn't edit it out, in case someone else makes the same mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My counter-example for injectivity doesn't work: I forgot that we are tensoring over $S$ (and not for example over $S_0$), and therefore
$$
x\otimes y+ (-y\otimes x)=x\otimes y- x\otimes y=0.
$$
Also, I couldn't use that the tensor-product commutes with the direct sum, because $S_n$ is an $S_0$-module and not an $S$-module.

I see now that $\phi$ is in fact an isomorphism; its inverse is given by
$$
\phi^{-1}:S(n+m)\to S(n)\otimes_S S(m),x\mapsto x\otimes 1.
$$
Note that this is an $S$-module map. It is also a graded map, since it maps $x\in S(n+m)_d=S_{n+m+d}$ to $x\otimes 1\in S(n)_{m+d}\otimes S(m)_{-m}$ which has degree $m+d-m=d$.